# Forced copy constructor in derived class with virtual destructor when using Auto

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual, destructor, auto

I was trying to derive std::unique_lock and I ran across an issue that I am not otherwise able to duplicate with a simpler class.  Below is compilable code that replicates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class A : public std::unique_lock<T>
{
 public:
  template<typename... Args>
  A(const std::string name, Args&&... args) : name_(name), 
  std::unique_lock<T>(args...) { }
  virtual ~A() {}  // if this destructor exists...
  private:
  std::string name_;
};


int main()
{
  std::timed_mutex tm;
  auto a = A<std::timed_mutex>("Hello", tm, std::defer_lock); // this line fails
  A<std::timed_mutex> a("Hello", tm, std::defer_lock); // this line works
  return 0;
}
```

If the virtual destructor exists ( which I need for my actual class ), then I cannot use the line with auto to instantiate the class because ultimately the ctor in std::unique_lock gets called is the deleted one that takes a const T& mutex which is deleted (b/c the lock class can't  deal with const mutexes).  I assume its calling that deleted const ctor because for some reason its calling the copy constructor in A() that takes as input a const &A (according to the error logs below).  If I simply use the non auto style instantiation code (labelled), then it compiles fine.

I'm using gcc 5.4.1 with the 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) setting.  I've tried 14 and 17 as well, so I assume its not the cpp I'm using.

Comment: There's no point having a virtual destructor if the class is never derived from. (And if you do derive from this class it substantially changes the question)

Comment: This class has to be a candidate for encapsulation rather than derivation, surely?

Comment: The point of the virtual dtor is to ensure that the dtor of the base class gets called which is important for a std::unique_lock.

Comment: When you say encapsulation, is that the same as composition?  I sent a toy example for brevity and clarity, but my purpose is to do some record keeping when this class is constructed and destructed for debugging purposes, so it’s just a unique lock  that records some data.

Comment: Base classes' destructors are always run.  A `virtual` destructor ensures that the most derived class's destructor gets run when an object is `delete`d via a pointer to a parent class with a `virtual` destructor.  Since `std::unique_lock` does not have a `virtual` destructor, your destructor will not be run if an `A` is `delete`d via a pointer to `std::unique_lock`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood something that I had read and had tunnel vision while trying to ensure that the lock would get unlocked on destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will not implicitly generate a move-constructor if your class contains a user-declared destructor, copy-constructor, or assignment operator.  Since `A` has no move-constructor, the compiler falls back to the copy-constructor, which is implicitly deleted because `std::unique_lock`'s copy-constructor is deleted.

You can explicitly declare a move-constructor to get things working:

```
template<class T>
class A : public std::unique_lock<T>
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  A(const std::string name, Args&&... args)
    : std::unique_lock<T>(args...),
      name_(name)
  { }
  A(A&&) = default;
  virtual ~A() {}
private:
  std::string name_;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4222de0b8c54a01)

You should also probably declare a move-assignment operator, but that's not necessary in this case.